# ORA-44001: invalid schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, impdp

I have an Oracle database dump which contains the dump of three schemas for e.g. `alpha` `bravo` `charlie` in one file, exported through `EXPDP`.

Now when I am trying to import these with the following command:

```
IMPDP alpha/alpha FULL=Y DUMPFILE=alpha06022014.dmp LOGFILE=alpha.log;
```

...after a couple of lines I get this error which is probably because I am supplying the credentials of only one schema in the command?

> ```
> ...
> ...
> ...
>
> ORA-31684: Object type VIEW:"alpha"."table1" already exists
> ORA-31684: Object type VIEW:"alpha"."object" already e
> xists
> ORA-39126: Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.PUT_DDL [VIEW:"bravo"."
> VW_NDC_CONFIG_REPLY"]
> ORA-44001: invalid schema
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 6273
>
> ----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
>   object      line  object
>   handle    number  name
> 25BA9BC0     14916  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
> 25BA9BC0      6300  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
> 25BA9BC0     12689  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
> 25BA9BC0     11968  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
> 25BA9BC0      3279  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
> 25BA9BC0      6889  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
> 25BA9BC0      1262  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
> 25A03A14         2  anonymous block
>
> Job "alpha"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_02" stopped due to fatal error at 11:26:41
>
> D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\BIN>
> ```

If yes, then how can I import all three schemas?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import data into a different schema you need to grant `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` role to the user. Oracle MOS Doc ID 351598.1.

Or you can use SYS user:

```
impdp \'/ as sysdba\' FULL=Y DUMPFILE=alpha06022014.dmp LOGFILE=alpha.log
```